# How is the count in Top Reviewers Today 5, but the count in number of flagged posts is only 3 on the Webmasters Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, review, flags

Today I have flagged 3 posts (First Posts- 3 and Late Posts - 0), but when I clicked *review -> recent reviews* it showed me that I have flagged 5 posts in First Posts and 0 Late Posts.
When I clicked the helpful flags count in my profile page, it showed 3 for today. Then how is the count in Top Reviewers Today 5?

Screenshot for reference where I have mentioned my system time also:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 because of a well-stated problem, -1 because you didn't even take a look at the most well-known links to find out the differences between a review and a flag. Guess I'm not voting.

Answer (score 5):

The Top Reviewers shows the amount of reviews you did, not the amount of posts you flagged from review. If you selected "No Action Needed" or do something else than flagging (except Skip), then that also counts as a review.

Comment: Oh God! I didn't think in that way. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Since I had confusion over Top Reviewers and helpful flag I asked this question. If this question is too basic I will delete it.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar you can't do that now that the answer has upvotes.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar You shouldn't just delete questions when there is an answer on it. It might help someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Really, if you did something in the review, like flagging, editing, voting, or even choose "No action needed", it counts as one review. Choosing Skip will not count as a valid review. Since you flagged 3 posts, that counts as 3 reviews. For the other two, you did a different action other than Skip, thus adding two more reviews for a total of five reviews.